# How to append newly created django object details in a results list with jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I have a one template of question detail and there are multiple answers of this question and below the answer there are replies.

While adding the new reply I want to prevent the page refresh so I used ajax and jquery. It creates the reply object in the database without page refresh but I got a problem in displaying that newly created reply object in the replies section.

How can i display the newly created reply object details under this div `<div id="comment{{answer.pk}}" class="media-heading">` upon creation?

After adding it displays results like this

```
ok 2020-07-16T12:35:36.879Z
```

Only after refresh it displays like this

```
ok 1 minute ago User
```

views

```
class AnswerReplyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        answer = Answer.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        reply = request.POST.get('reply')
        reply_obj = AnswerReply.objects.create(answer=answer, reply=reply, replied_by=request.user)
        data = {
        'reply': reply_obj.reply,
        'created': reply_obj.created,
        'replied_by': reply_obj.replied_by.first_name
             }
        return JsonResponse(data, status=200)
```

template

```
{% for answer in answers %}
  {% if answer.replies.all %}
           <div class="media-body">
              <div id="comment{{answer.pk}}" class="media-heading">
                    {% for reply in answer.replies.all %}
                         <small>{{reply.reply}}
                         </small>
                         <span class="time">{{reply.created|timesince}}ago</span>
                         <a href="{% url 'users:user_profile' %}" class="reply">{{reply.replied_by.first_name}} {{reply.replied_by.last_name}}</a><br>
                         {% endfor %}
                         </div>
                      </div>
                 {% endif %}
               {% endfor %}
```

jquery/ajax

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
{% for answer in answers %}
     $(function(){
    var $commentForm = $('#commentForm{{answer.pk}}')
    $commentForm.submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      var $formData = $(this).serialize()
      var $thisURL = $commentForm.attr('action')
      $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: $thisURL,
         data: $formData,
         dataType:'json',
         csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
         success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
              $('#comment{{answer.pk}}').append(data.reply, data.created, data.created_by)
              $("#commentForm{{answer.pk}}").toggle();
               console.log(data);
                },
      });

 });

  });

{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move out `media-body` div from for loop and append to `media-body` div.

`$('#comment{{answer.pk}}').append(html)` instead of this you should use `$('.media-body').append(html)`